# SWT ScrollableComposite filled with text, want to wrap horizontally and scroll vertically

Tags: java, layout, swt

I've got a `ScrolledComposite` set to take up the whole area of my shell, and I've got multiple Labels in a horizontal `RowLayout` inside it.  I'd like to make it so that when the window is resized the text would always reach all the way across, but right now it just keeps its original width.  On top of that, the text seems to go behind the scrollbar before wrapping.

Comment: Please post your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a [`GridLayout`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Flayout%2FGridLayout.html). With a grid layout you can make your controls re-size with the parent. you can have your labels divided either with equal space for each or different.

Set `widthHint` on each label and make them fill horizontally. They will fill up the parent whenever it is resized.

Comment: Using `widthHint` will in most cases result in the `Label` having exactly this size. You should use `horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL` and `grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true` instead.

Comment: I do not recall exactly now but I think for wrapping to work a width hint used to be necessary, along with fill alignment and excess grabbing of horizontal space. I think @zacaj can try this out if wrapping is not working as expected.

Comment: I see, I somehow missed the "wrapping part".